# Expression Tree No method Where on type System.Linq.Queryable

Tags: c#, list, .net-core, lambda, expression

I am testing dynamic expressions for a list but I have the following error.

CODE

```
List<DTOPreuab> modelolista = new List<DTOPreuab>();
modelolista.Add(new DTOPreuab { id = 1, nom = "test1" });
modelolista.Add(new DTOPreuab { id = 2, nom = "test2" });        
IQueryable<DTOPreuab> queryableData = modelolista.AsQueryable<DTOPreuab>();
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "nom");
GetStringMethod
Expression left = Expression.Call(pe, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
Expression right = Expression.Constant("test2");
Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);                    
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(e1, pe);        

MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] {  typeof(IEnumerable<DTOPreuab>)  },
            queryableData.Expression,
            lambda
            ); 
            IQueryable<string> results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(whereCallExpression);
            var response = results.ToArray();
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t09nC.jpg)

Comment: `Queryable.Where` takes an argument of type `IQueryable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply @pinkfloydx33 , but switch to IQueryable<T> and return No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well. Posts in which essential text content is only present in images are likely to be closed as lacking enough details.